# The question is about responsive website in mobile browser

Tags: responsive

i have an issue. my website is not looking same in all mobile browser its only appearing as responsive in (Firefox lite.) but when i am opening from chrome , edge (mobile browsers) it appearing as desktop site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following in  tag of your index page.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```